# How can I get the shotgun, if I have thrown away the stick

Tags: half-life-alyx

I have figured out that to get the shotgun, I need to bring the zombie holding it back up to ground level and use a stick to stop the wheel. But in trying initially to grab the gun, I have thrown all the objects down onto the floor below where I can no longer reach them.

Do I need to reload from an earlier save? Or is there some way to get more sticks or other objects to stick in the wheel?

Comment: i need to test it.. but, isn´t the stick retrievable with your magnet gloves?

Comment: Not sure if there are other stick-like objects up there, but you can actually climb/jump back up the wall you jumped down to get there, and go look for more items that way.

Comment: "All the objects" meaning all the trash and similar things that were on the same floor with the wheel thingy you took the stick from?

Comment: I can't get down to the floor below and survive. And I can't reach anything that far away with my magnetic gloves.